# How do I get tourist attractions around zip code using OpenStreetMap?

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap

I want to get all tourist attractions around a zip code in the US. How do I do that from OpenStreetMap api?

I have found this http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:tourism

But I'm not sure how to use it.

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=135+pilkington+avenue,+birmingham&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&tourism=attraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) e.g. with the query wizard to show for the current bounding box the available objects.

To do this for a zip code instead of a bounding box this is much more complicated even in a properly mapped region like Germany, because to my knowledge there are no relations (or very rarely) that map a zip code to a boundary polygon. You could obtain several addresses with zip codes and then create a kind of a boundary for it but that won't be very precise. Regarding US you also have probably less features like zip code mapped due to the Tiger import (less mapping activity), not sure.